# считывание с Serial1 порта

Tags: c, arduino, serial

arduino mega принимает на порт Serial1 сигнал (значение millis() arduino nano) с модуля RS485 ,вывод сразу в Serial на экран компа работает но сохранить значение в переменную и дальнейшая работа с не получается, пробовал сохранение в массив, но все безуспешно

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Blynk.h>
#include <Ethernet2.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleEthernet2.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>


#define DIR 30
#define DIR1 31
/*
      26 октября 16:20
        Pins 10, 11, 12 and 13 are reserved for Ethernet module.
        DON'T use them in your sketch directly!
*/

// SoftwareSerial RS485(50,51);  // (RX,TX)
//  ro - RX 
//  di - TX
BlynkTimer timer1;
BlynkTimer outputtimer ;

  char auth[] ="auth";

  int i = 0 ;

void  GetData()
{
  if (Serial1.available())
  {
    i = Serial1.read();
  }

}
void OutputData()
{ 
  Serial.print("i = ");
  Serial.println(i);
}
void setup()
{
  Blynk.begin(auth);
  // RS485.begin(9600);


  attachInterrupt(19,GetData,CHANGE);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  
  timer1.setInterval(5,GetData);
  outputtimer.setInterval(1000,OutputData);

  pinMode(DIR,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(DIR,LOW);
  
  pinMode(DIR1,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(DIR,LOW);

} 


void loop()
{ 
  
Blynk.run();
timer1.run();
outputtimer.run();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас функция `getData()` нигде не вызывается.

Comment: она вызывается через таймер   timer1.setInterval(5,GetData);

Comment: Каждые 5 миллисекунд?